# Using focus event to show another element

Tags: javascript, css

i would like to open `<details>` element when a relative `<link>` element gets focused or clicked

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#job-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <details>
            <summary id="job-1">some text</summary>
            <table>       
            </table>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary id="job-2">some text</summary>
            <table>
            </table>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary id="job-3">some text</summary>
            <table>
            </table>
        </details>
    </div>
</section>
```

if possible i would like to do this with javascript

Comment: Really unclear...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the reason why you want to implement this functionality with JS when it's already working as an HTML5 feature?

Comment: I edited the post, it should be clear now (if @Vin accepts it...)

Comment: I think I got it... When one of the links is clicked, additionally to jumping to the summary element, you want it to open the details block as well as if the summary element had been clicked. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah exactly @connum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all the `a` tags and attach a click event listener to each of them that triggers the click of the associated `summary` element:

**Update:** As you probably don't want to close the `details` when they are already open, I added a check for that.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('section ul li a'); // would be better to use an id or at least classes here...

for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var summaryEl = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href'));
    // only trigger if the details are not already open
    if (!summaryEl.parentNode.open) {
      summaryEl.click();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#job-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <details>
            <summary id="job-1">some text</summary>
            <table> 
            <tr><td>test content</td></tr>
            </table>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary id="job-2">some text</summary>
            <table>
            <tr><td>test content</td></tr>
            </table>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary id="job-3">some text</summary>
            <table>
            <tr><td>test content</td></tr>
            </table>
        </details>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: that could work i will try it out soon and report back thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#job-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#job-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div class="details" id="job-1">
            <summary>some text</summary>
            <table>       
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="details" id="job-2">
            <summary>some text</summary>
            <table>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="details" id="job-3">
            <summary>some text</summary>
            <table>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Using css only:**

css:

```
.details { display:none; }
.details:focus { display:block; }
```

More : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

**Or using css and js:**

css:

```
.details { display:none; }
```

js:

```
function hideAllDetails(){
    document.getElementByClassName("details").style = '';
}
document.getElementById("job-1").addEventListenner('focus',function(evvent){
     hideAllDetails();
     event.target.style = "display:block";
});
// duplicate for every elements you want
```

**Or using [jquery](https://jquery.com/)**

css:

```
.details { display:none; }
```

js:

```
$('.details').on('focus',function(){
   $('.details').css('display','none');
   $(this).css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have posted JavaScript centric answers I figured I would chime in with a different solution using only CSS. If you slightly  restructure your HTML so the detail element would follow its respective button, you could do this with pure CSS.

You could then restyle/move each detail section via CSS. Example as follows:

```css
.btn{
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:60px;
  height:20px;
}

.next{
  display:none;
}

.btn:focus + .next{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" tabindex="1">Click Me</div>
<div class="next">
  this should be showing on click
</div>
<div class="btn" tabindex="1">Click Me</div>
<div class="next">
  this should be showing on click
</div>
```

Comment: i may try this in another project as it seens like a cool way to implement the feature but for this project it will take alot of reconstrution due to how everything is layed out on the page already

Comment: @vin Understandable! Definitely easier with JavaScript!